# Should wrap property of undefined: navigator.app

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon, stub

I am trying to stub `navigator.app.loadUrl` which I use for redirecting like: `navigator.app.loadUrl('www.redirecturl.com', {openExternal: true});`

Doing this gives the error:

> Should wrap property of object

I am trying to stub this method using: `var navigatorStub = sinon.stub(navigator.app, 'loadUrl');` What am I doing wrong?

Stubbing properties of navigator does work. Like `navigator.splashscreen`.

**EDIT:**

I also tried to accomplish this by doing:

```
var navigatorStub = sinon.stub(navigator);
var navigatorAppStub = sinon.stub(navigatorStub.app, 'loadUrl');
```

This gives the same result.

Comment: You forgot the quotes around the domain name.

Comment: I did, thanks. But that was not part of my issue.

Comment: Problem is that `navigator.app` is `undefined`, and so your first parameter to the `sinon.stub(` _object_ `, ` _property_ `)` method call is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jsdom you can fake the navigator object in your Jsdom config.

```
if (!navigator.app) {
  navigator.app = {};
}

if (!navigator.app.loadUrl) {
   navigator.app.loadUrl function(url, props) {
     exec(null, null, APP_PLUGIN_NAME, "loadUrl", [url, props]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not using Jsdom. Do I need it for this?

Comment: It can help. I think problem is here that navigator.app object isn't exist.
Maybe this conversion will give you some idea https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1129#issuecomment-240055320.

Answer (score 0):

The following works, but I am not sure if this is the right way to deal with this kind of undefined objects. Better solutions are still welcome. :)

```
var navigatorStub = sinon.stub(navigator);
    navigatorStub.app = {
       loadUrl: function () {
       }
    };
var navigatorAppStub = sinon.stub(navigatorStub.app, 'loadUrl');
```